# Passing 2 values through php URL

Tags: php

I have following code to pass values through URL:

```
<a href="menu_food_categories.php?value=1"><img src="images/veg.png" width="100%"></a> 
<a  href="menu_food_categories.php?value=2"><img src="images/Non-veg.png"   width="100%"></a> 
<a href="menu_food_categories.php?value=3"><img src="images/combined.png" width="100%"></a> 
<a  href="menu_food_categories.php?value=4"><img src="images/beverages.png" width="100%"></a>
```

Now I want to pass value 1 and 2 along with value 3,
anyone can help please.

Comment: How about using `val1=someVal&val2=otherVal`?

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="test.php?value1=1&value2=2&value3=3">test</a>   

<?php
    print_r($_GET);
    // Output : Array ( [value1] => 1 [value2] => 2 [value3] => 3 )
?>
```

Comment: What  is not working ? What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: This one is not working: <a href="test.php?value1=1&value2=2&value3=3"></a>

Comment: What do you want to achieve when you click on one of your links ? What value do you want to get ?

Comment: There are veg,non veg,combined,drinks are food type, they have id's 1,2,3,4 respectively  and fetching data from database

Answer (score 0):

You simply can concatenate the parameters using an ampersand (&)

it would look like this

```
menu_food_categories.php?value1=1&value2=2&value3=3
```

Comment: notice the changed get parameter names from 'value' to 'value1', maybe you forgot to alter the server code which handles the get parameter?

Comment: This is the get parameter: $foodtype = $_GET['value']; from menu_food_categories.php file

Comment: and this is  where i'm sending this parameter :  <a href="menu_food_items.php?value=<?php echo $foodtype;  ?>&id=<?=$res['id']?>"></a>

Comment: well then, change $_GET['value'] to whatever you desire, like value1

Comment: But i also need to need to send value2, value3 along with value, because value parameter is same for these 4 values

Comment: you do have the 2 possibilities but in any case you need to change your server side logic, because the receiving values differ. first: my suggestion, but you need to extract each value (value1, value2...) or you use the answer @Dinesh Belakare gave you, but here you must handle the array with the different food types on the serverside. if you also do need help with that, edit the question and provide your code or create a new question for this new problem

Answer (score 0):

Add comma separated values in url

```
<a href="menu_food_categories.php?value=1,2,3">
```

And Then use explode function(i.e `explode(',',$_GET['value'])`) to get it in array on "menu_food_categories.php" file.